# chgrp permanently for a directory

Tags: unix, permissions, file-permissions

I'm running a CentOS 5.0 server with root access. The `/var/www` folder was originally set recursively with root as the owner and group.  So I did a `chgrp -R webdevs /var/www` and a `chmod -R g+rwx /var/www` command to give all members of the webdevs group read/write access. These changes work as required for all preexisting files.  However, when user *examplewebdev* creates a new file in the `/var/www` directory, the group defaults to *examplewebdev* instead of *webdevs*.   How do I change the defaults for new file creation?

Comment: You need to ask this question on ServerFault.com.

Comment: @Amardeep: Not necessarily, there are also ACL subroutines, [`acl(3)`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=acl&sektion=3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to play with ACLs: `man setfacl`.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.vanemery.com/Linux/ACL/linux-acl.html#default

Answer (score 0):

I use 'newgrp' command but I think it applies only in the shell you are currently in.